# iOS / HealthKit - server traffic logs tend to spike after app updates

Tags: ios, healthkit

So, I have an app that runs an HKObserverQuery in the background. We take data from HealthKit and push it up to our server for further analysis.

When we do an app update, however, we usually see a spike in requests made to our server. It usually times from when the app becomes available in the store, and usually dies down a few days later.

My question is - when an app is updated, does it try to resume a particular state or something after the installation occurs? Our data fetch/upload process is called in applicationDidFinishLaunching, and my only hunch is that after the update occurs it tries to resume a state, thus invoking that function.

Any insight in to this would be real helpful. Thanks!

EDIT: my curiosity exists because I can't imagine all of our users opening the app after an update occurs, especially the auto-updaters. So my question revolves around if iOS attempts to load the app after installing an update to verify it, henceforth calling applicationDidFinishLaunching, but without bringing the app to the foreground.

Comment: `applicationDidFinishLaunching` is not invoked when an app becomes foreground from background, but is called when an app is launched just after installed or updated.

Comment: I understand that this occurs when the app is launched, not necessarily when an app becomes active (foreground), however I'm curious if during the installation process it tries to load the app or something to verify installation. I can't imagine all of our users immediately opening the app after an app update occurs, especially if they have auto-update turned on.